# LinkLabel... open in default web browser?

Tags: c#, linklabel

Is it possible to open a `LinkLabel` in the default computers web browser?

Comment: well it's the default behavior once you have set a proper valid url. What kind of problem are you having and how does your code look like so far?

Comment: I was looking in the Properties for something that would start it. Originally I tried just setting a url address to the .Text property and of course that didn't work.

Comment: i don't understand the existence of this control, probably because i do don understand how to use it

Answer (score 56, accepted):

yes - you can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url)` in the "link clicked" event.

Comment: so something like this
        private void linkSubmit_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(linkSubmit.text as String);
        }

Comment: Thank you... :D :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035650/2152973

Answer (score 11):

I always use them like this. This way you will get the default browser to open the URL.

```
ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://www.google.com");
Process.Start(sInfo);
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution inspired by [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320478) that works without hardcoding the URL into your code:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string url;
    if (e.Link.LinkData != null)
        url = e.Link.LinkData.ToString();
    else
        url = linkLabel1.Text.Substring(e.Link.Start, e.Link.Length);

    if (!url.Contains("://"))
        url = "https://" + url;

    var si = new ProcessStartInfo(url);
    Process.Start(si);
    linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;
}
```

You can then easily use LinkArea to have un-hyperlinked text around the link.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution it is better:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(((LinkLabel)sender).Text);
}
```

Comment: Agreed - code reuse using the sender object beats a dedicated handler per link/control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Solution:

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    linkLabel1.Links.Add(0, linkLabel1.Text.Length, "https://www.example.com");
}
```

And Here the Click-Function:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = e.Link.LinkData.ToString(),
        UseShellExecute = true
    });
}
```