# C# basic linkLabel doesn't open url, exception unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, linklabel

This is my simple code, yet it throws me an exception for some reason

```
    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome", "https://www.google.com/");
            }
```

The Exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: specify your tags : add 'WinForms' and which version of .Net you are using, so the community can help you efficiently.

Comment: apparently i am using .NET v4.0

Answer (score 1):

To open a url using the WinForms's linkLabel component do

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.url.com"); // will automaticaly redirect the user to his default web browser 
}
```

find more in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel?view=net-5.0).
take a look there : [already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154256/linklabel-open-in-default-web-browser).
good luck.

Comment: In .Net Framework (since `UseShellExecute = true` by default). In .Net Core / .Net 5+, it defaults to `UseShellExecute = false`. So you have to set it to `true` beforehand.